# Replace all occurrences of a regexp group after processing the string in the group

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this one:

```
text = '''this \sum 1,2 \end is three and \sum 2,3,4 \end is nine'''
```

and I have a function that adds numbers in a string

```
def add(numbers):
    return sum(map(lambda x:int(x), numbers.split(",")))
```

How can I, using regexps, replace all instances of `'\\sum (.+?) \\end'` by passing the group through the `add` function?
i.e. the string above should be:

```
'''this 3 is three and 9 is nine'''
```

I can get the `"1,2"` and `"2,3,4"` using `findall` and add them, but how do I insert them back in the text where they are supposed to go? perhaps a combination of `findall` and `split`? is there a more straightforward way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `re.findall()`, use `re.sub()` and use a function to process each group.

The return value of the function is used as the replacement string:

```
re.sub(r'\\sum ([\d,]+) \\end', lambda m: str(add(m.group(1))), text)
```

The `lambda` creates a function that accepts one argument, the match object. It returns a string based on the number group, passed through `add()`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''this \sum 1,2 \end is three and \sum 2,3,4 \end is nine'''
>>> def add(numbers):
...     return sum(map(lambda x:int(x), numbers.split(",")))
... 
>>> re.sub(r'\\sum ([\d,]+) \\end', lambda m: str(add(m.group(1))), text)
'this 3 is three and 9 is nine'
```

Comment: thanks! I totally missed the repl as a function portion of the documentation.